# Redis key eviction clarification

Tags: redis

Im evaluating the opensource redis and came to a confusion regarding the max memory settings and eviction policies.

Suppose,my maxmemory is 4GB and data size also 4GB and  set  maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru. What my question is when new keys are written to Redis the evicted keys will be lost from system permanently or will be stored in disk so that I can reuse when ever required.

Thank you,

Comment: The evicted keys are lost forever.

Comment: ok In that case memory size is the actual data we can store in redis. Btw suppose I create three nodes with 4GB ram in each , I can store 12GB of data in redis cluster?

Comment: Yes - the cluster's purpose is allowing horizontal scaling of resources. Each node adds its respective capacity to the cluster.